# .Net Core 2.0 "Generate Nuget package on build" issue with Post-build events

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, .net-core, nuget-package, .net-core-2.0

The new .NET Core 2.0 projects provide and easy and convenient way to create Nuget Package from the project output. Just click on the "Generate Nuget package on build" check box and it is done.
[image]
It works fine but I have an issue with Post-build events.
I want to copy all of the packages from a solution after each build to a specific folder. So I use the "*Post-build event command line*" with a script:

```
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)..*.nupkg" "$(SolutionDir)..\WebServicePracticesNuget\" /Y /I
```

And sometimes it works fine sometimes not at all. So far my investigation concluded that the Nuget package creation is not part of the build process itself. So the script (sometimes) will triggered before the package was generated and it is unpredictable. My solution is to add some delay. Unfortunately "**timeout x**" is not working with Post-build events. So I used the fallback option:

```
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 4 > NUL
```

Which makes it almost reliable (~95%) but I think it is "poor man's" solution. And looks ridiculous in a Post-build event script. I have already [reported](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/157079/generate-nuget-package-on-build-issue-with-post-bu.html) this issue to the VS team. But not much comments or solution so far.

So my question is: does anybody have the same issue? Or any idea for a better solution then I have now?
Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `GeneratePackageOnBuild` feature executes the `Pack` target after `Build` so the post build event will potentially run before the NuGet packages have been created. In VS 15.3+, when you create a post-build event, it will create a `Target` element in the project file. You can change the `AfterTargets` attribute on it to `AfterTargets="Pack"` to run after packing and not after the core .net build. But it is a bit of a fragile approach.

The pack target will respect the `PackageOutputPath` msbuild property, which is what `dotnet pack`'s `--output` parameter would set.

Since `xcopy` only works on windows, the most versatile solution would be to use msbuild to set up the property during the build.

For example you could put a `Directory.Build.props` file next to the solution file (directory above all projects) with the following contents:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageOutputPath>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)nupkgs</PackageOutputPath>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

This file will be automatically imported into all project files in the directory hierarchy blow this file and set the target directory for the generated `.nupkg` files to a folder named `nupkgs` next to the `Directory.Build.props` file. It also enables the "generate package build" feature for all projects that support it ("sdk-based" projects like .net standard / .net core libraries) so you don't have to set it up in VS or edit all project files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Right now I'm testing out @patutin suggestion. It looks promising. Could you explain to me why is it, as you wrote: "But it is a bit of a fragile approach."?
The automatically imported project settings sounds good. I'm not an expert on MSbuild config. But certainly I will look into that as well. Thank you.

Comment: Depends on what else is in that post build step. The package output path should also include symbol packages (`dotnet pack --include-symbols` or `<IncludeSymbols>true</IncludeSymbols>` in the msbuild file)

Comment: Ok tried it out that was easy and works like a charm. Actually I suffered from setting up the same config over and over on UI e.g: Author, IconUrl, etc.. And I had some issue with <PublishDocumentationFile>true</PublishDocumentationFile> it has to be set in the project file in order to pack the XML documentation as well. I put everything into the .props file. Best solution ever :) thanks.

Comment: @MartinUllrich I am facing similar issue with `GeneratePackageOnBuild` which works in my local machine but not in VSTS Azure Build pipeline. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52783149/building-nuget-package-with-nuget-pack-csproj-and-nuget-push-created-package 

Can you please look at the same and guide

Answer (score 8):

You can configure [msbuild task order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/msbuild-targets#target-build-order) inside the project file.

Comment: Thanks for the link the <Target Name="CopyPackage" AfterTargets="Pack"> looks very promising. And way more elegant :) I will test it further with all the projects but hope it will work fine.

Comment: This is correct answer for me. Just write in yours csproj file this: 


`<Target Name="CopyPackage" AfterTargets="Pack">
        <Copy
                SourceFiles="$(OutputPath)..\$(PackageId).$(PackageVersion).nupkg"
                DestinationFolder="$(SolutionDir)NuGet\BuildOut\"
        />
    </Target>`