# Run NuGet add in Visual Studio 2022 post build event

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, post-build-event

I've created a local NuGet feed for some testing.  In an attempt to automate the process, I've tried to create a post-build event to execute the 'NuGet add' for the package.  The NuGet add fails with:

> Provided Nupkg file 'XXXXX\bin\x64\Debug\XXXXX.1.0.0.nupkg' is not
> found.

However, when I look at the folder, the 'nupkg' file is where I expect it to be.  I'm using the following command in the post-build event:

```
nuget add "$(ProjectDir)bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\$(ProjectName).$(PackageVersion).nupkg" -Source "C:\XXXXX\NuGet Local Source"
```

Is this a problem with 'timing'?

How can I perform the 'NuGet add' in a post-build event?

I found [How to run 'nuget add' as a post-build evnet in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38000691/how-to-run-nuget-add-as-a-post-build-event-in-visual-studio), but, I can't tell what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging, I found a workaround.  I found [.Net Core 2.0 "Generate Nuget package on build" issue with Post-build events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47576451/net-core-2-0-generate-nuget-package-on-build-issue-with-post-build-events) that mentioned using "Pack" as an 'AfterTargets'.  The current build events tab does not offer 'Pack' as an option.  So, the procedure I used was to fill in the post-build event, save the project and close it.  Then, I edit the .csproj file and change this line in the file:

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="Pack">
```

This allowed me to run the 'nuget' command from the post-build event.